# how to use namespace of external project?

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces

**Currently :**

I have the following Using in my program.

```
using Mtx;
```

which allows me to use Mtx.* properties. It refers to a file in "Externals" folder.

*Path is :*    `Externals/Mtx.dll`

**Needed :**

However, for debugging purposes, I'd like to now have the whole mtx solution in external and use it.

*Path is :*    `Externals/Mtx/(solution in there with all folders)`

How can I do so, so instead of Using refers to the `Mtx.dll`, it now refers to the solution and build it has part of its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are misunderstanding some concepts and mixing things. Let me explain with your own explanation:

> I have the following Using in my program.
>
> using Mtx; which allows me to use Mtx.* properties. It refers to a
>   file in "Externals" folder.
>
> Path is :  Externals/Mtx.dll

The `using` keyword allows you to use the classes inside a namespace without typing the whole namespace everytime. It has nothing to do with dll classes, you can use all the public dlls insidea class just using the whole namespace + the class name only adding it as a project reference.

> Needed :
>
> However, for debugging purposes, I'd like to now have the whole mtx
>   solution in external and use it

For debugging purposes all you need are the pdb's of the dlls used and you will be able to debug any class considering you have its source code without changing anything else.

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer! sorry for the long delay, I tried to understand stuff before asking evident question. However about the pdb's I won't be able to use them. We work with subversion, and with the environment I work on, we must be able to use another solution without building it. For example, my current solution would need to be "using" another solution. We want to work without the dll, It's not just for debugging purpose.