# how to use class of other project in a solution (internal)?

Tags: c#, namespaces

**Environment :**

In C#, I have a solution with many project. They were added with *.csproj files.

**Problem :**

In a project, you can use classes of other files through namespace. However, is there a way to use namespace and classes of another project in the same solution?

Comment: you need add reference to project where placed classes and namespaces which you want

Comment: Can you clarify why you wrote "internal" in your question title? If you are referring to [C#'s `internal` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this could very well entirely change the answer to your question.

Comment: If you just want to use files with code from another solution then you can add this files as link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I set internal because the project is part of the solution (I guess I could use it even if it would not be a part of it). For example I had another question about the same problem, but without having the project in the solution. I wanted to distinguish between both.

Comment: The link to other question which serve the same purpose but without having the project in the actual solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761543/how-to-use-namespace-of-external-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio you should have a "References" area in the Solution Explorer. Right click that and click "Add Reference..."
From here, it's just a matter of locating where you other code is on your machine.

Edit: [Here is some additional information on DLLs, in case it helps you.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228390%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)